# Azure Service Fabric logging to Azure Diagnostics is not working

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I've tried to setup transferring Service Fabric logs to Azure Diagnostic and I have used this article

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-setup-wad/

```
[EventSource(Name = "MyCompany-MyApp-WebApi")]
internal sealed class ServiceEventSource : EventSource {}
```

And I've added a new provider to Clustermanifest

```
{
  "provider": "MyCompany-MyApp-WebApi",
  "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
  "DefaultEvents": {
    "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"
  }
},
```

It actually sends all logs to Azure Diagnostic, but all log entries are empty (see pic)

[azure table pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0cTy.jpg)

Comment: Same problem for me

Comment: I've tried ETWEventTable. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify the eventDestination value as EventTable only. The cluster manifest should look like :

{
  "provider": "MyCompany-MyApp-WebApi",
  "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
  "DefaultEvents": {
    "eventDestination": "EventTable "
  }
},

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/venkateshwj/AzureLogger) . Sample has ARM template to create your cluster with Diagnostics also help you to have same diagnostics storage table for multiple clusters. Also it can be used for Azure services like web api. Would be glad if this helps